# Where I run ioic serve error message @ionic/cli-utils/bootstrap'

Tags: ionic3

In my project, When I was in use ionic3 this framework, often meet with ionic serve start time, a Google can't find problems, feel very confused, want to ask everyone in the community you a great god, hope to solve
My operation is as follows:

[image]

> Error info:  Cannot find module '@ionic/cli-utils/bootstrap':

Comment: what does `ionic info` output? can you add to your question?

Answer (score 0):

i resolve this error with install @ionic/cli-utils

```
sudo npm install -g @ionic/cli-utils
```